# java commons dbutils: multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: java, sql, apache-commons-dbutils

I'm executing this query:

```
 SELECT psq_id, question_text 
 FROM presales_question
 WHERE psq_id IN(SELECT zz.psq_id FROM productservice_psq as zz WHERE zz.ps_id = 1)
```

When I execute it directly in SQL Server Management Studio, it works.
When I execute it with a standard Java Statement & Result Set, it works.
When I execute it using the [Apache Commons DBUtils library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/) (v 1.5), I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The multi-part identifier "zz.ps_id" could not be bound. Query: SELECT psq_id, question_text FROM presales_question  WHERE psq_id IN(SELECT zz.psq_id FROM productservice_psq as zz WHERE zz.ps_id = ?)  Parameters: [1]
at org.apache.commons.dbutils.AbstractQueryRunner.rethrow(AbstractQueryRunner.java:363)
at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:350)
at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:211)
```

It seems the problem is not with the query, but with the dbutils library. Digging into the source, I see the error is thrown when dbutils calls the `getParameterMetaData()` method of the Statement.  I'm still unsure how to fix this.

My interim solution has been to edit the source code of the dbutils library and disable the call to `getParameterMetaData()` (see line 196 of AbstractQueryRunner.java). All it does is check that the param count passed in matches what's found in the query and throw an error if !=.  I'm OK with skipping that check since the query will fail anyway if the params don't match.

Comment: check your jdbc driver, use the latest libs.

Comment: I have the latest sqljdbc4.jar drivers. Like I said, the query itself works. The problem is the getParameterMetaData() throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

**You queries differs, check the table names and do a new try.**

```
SELECT psq_id, text 
FROM ps_question
WHERE psq_id IN (
  SELECT zz.psq_id FROM productservice_psq as zz WHERE zz.ps_id = 1
)
```

and the one it fails

```
SELECT psq_id, question_text 
FROM presales_question  
WHERE psq_id IN (
  SELECT zz.psq_id FROM productservice_psq as zz WHERE zz.ps_id = ?
)
```

1. You have text in the first and question_text in the next.
2. Table name is ps_question in first query and presales_question in the other.

Be 100% sure that the query is ok, you don't need any alias for the table zz. You could remove this details.

---

**Might be old jdbc drivers you use.**

Download the latest drivers,

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774

---

**Try to give 1 and run the query again, will it run? or will it fail?**

change the ? to 1

```
SELECT psq_id, question_text FROM presales_question  
WHERE psq_id IN (
  SELECT zz.psq_id FROM productservice_psq as zz WHERE zz.ps_id = ? <-- change 1
)
```

Comment: The different params were just me trying to simplify the query names when i posted it.
I have the latest drivers from MS.
The change 1 did not help.

Comment: I added the zz alias to do some troubleshooting. I understand it's not necessary, but i get the same error without it.

Comment: Yes simple queries work. Anything that is selecting from a single table (not using joins or nested selects) works.

Comment: There was a bug (i think it has been fixed some versions back) when using aliases, thats why I asked for removing the zz, see thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.sqlserver.jdbcdriver/XUGoJ_334Js

Comment: OK. more debugging. After removing the zz alias and changing the ? to 1, it executed successfully and getParameterMetaData() worked.  This is a problem though because I need (prefer) to use prepared statements with ?'s in them to prevent sql injection

Comment: Can you try to split the query in 2 parts? first query that finds the psq_id from productservice_psq and the next query gets the text from presales_question.

Comment: I can... but shouldn't have to. The problem is fully due to the ? in the SQL when asking for getParameterMetaData(). The alias has not caused any problems. It seems to be an issue with MS SQL JDBC driver. I haven't run into this with MySQL.